Identify this French film
This is really vague so I have no idea how possible this is going to be!
Some years ago I half watched a film. Basically it was just on in the room whilst I was doing something else and as it was in French with English subtitles I didn't really know what was going on, but for some reason it's stayed with me and I'd love to find out what it was so I can watch it properly.
This isn't a lot to go on but it seemed to be in two parts. The first part was set around a country house with some sort of family gathering. I got the feeling the was a couple and the girl cheated on the bloke and it all went bad.
The second part, was set many years later. It looked like the bloke had written a film about the events in the first part and then persuaded the original people to act out their own parts. 
What was cool was it looked like the set the filmed this film within the film on was the set they filmed the first part of the actual film on, a bit like the first part actually was the film being made in the second part?
Like I said, I wasn't really watching and could have misunderstood!
EDIT  I think it's sometime around 2005, give or take a few years either way. And I'm pretty sure the film was quite recent when I saw it.

How many years is some years? Please try to be specific so it is easier to answer your question.

Oh yeah, I forgot that bit! So, I've been trying to work out when I saw it. I think it's sometime around 2005, give or take a few years either way. And I'm pretty sure the film was quite recent when I saw it.
